# azure storage for logging

Tags: logging, azure, azure-storage

I currently have a pet project which is an asp.net mvc website running in azure. The site is currently running in "free" mode, so I'm only paying for the expense of a SQL Azure database. I want to be able to do some logging/tracing from my site and [I've read](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459699/Logging-Using-Azure-Table-Storage) that using table storage is a viable option since writing to the local disk to not an option. My question is what do I need to create within the Azure portal to get all this working? I know that I will need a storage account but do I need to create a "Cloud service" and the vm that comes along with it? Is it possible to make use of table storage for logging without incurring the cost of creating a stand alone VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you listed above, all you'll need is a storage account in Windows Azure which you can create through portal (as you mentioned). You would not need a "Cloud Service".

There will be storage transactions and storage costs associated with the logging data however table storage is extremely cheap and I wouldn't worry much about it just yet given the nature of the project. Just ensure that your storage account and website are in the same data center.

Comment: Gaurav is correct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411544.aspx for more step by step type instructions.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. The key for me was understanding that for an Azure website in free mode, table storage should be configured directly via a web.config rather than via service configuration file (.cscfg). This article helped the most. https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/